# How do I start network from 23.04 console?

Tags: networking, upgrade, 23.04

I upgraded 22.10 to 23.04 via do-release-upgrade. After the upgrade installs the new file and does its configuration, the system reboots, but dumps the user in the Recovery Menu.
Going to the shell, the network doesn't work. The file systems are all mounted and working, including the zfs drives.

But...the boot doesn't ever get to the graphical interface.
To solve this, it would be useful to have the network working.

Here's what I've tried, to get the network to work...

```
% ping ubuntu.com
ping: ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
% ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 3138  bytes 223244 (223.2 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 3138  bytes 223244 (223.2 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
% cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Here's what's in /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml

```
% cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      match:
        macaddress: 48:9e:bd:0e:ec:fa
      optional: true
      set-name: eth0
  wifis:
    wlp0s20f3:
      access-points:
        "It Hertz when IP":
          password: '@*S obvious as the light of d9y'
      dhcp4: true
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.68/24
      routes: 
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.255
      match:
        macaddress: 8c:55:4a:9b:ae:2e
      optional: true
```

Then I tried to start netplan:

```
% netplan apply
Failed to connect system bus: Connection refused
Falling back to a hard restart of systemd-networkd.service
%
```

Then I tried ifconfig:

```
% ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 20866  bytes 1485964 (1.4 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 20866  bytes 1485964 (1.4 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So, then I tried bringing up eth0 and wifi:

```
% ifconfig eth0 up
% ifconfig wlp0s20f3 up
% ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 48:9e:bd:0e:ec:fa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 2017  bytes 224878 (224.8 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 4  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 14  bytes 1116 (1.1 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 20866  bytes 1485964 (1.4 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 20866  bytes 1485964 (1.4 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp0s20f3: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 8c:55:4a:9b:ae:2e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
% ping ubuntu.com
ping: ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
% service NetworkManager start
Job for NetworkManager.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status NetworkManager.service" and "journalctl -xeu NetworkManager.service" for details
% systemctl status NetworkManager.service
○ NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
 Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-05-02 13:24:05 PDT; 3min 10s ago
   Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
Process: 39088 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 39088 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    CPU: 19ms

May 02 13:24:05 Kel-Omen systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 63.
May 02 13:24:05 Kel-Omen systemd[1]: Stopped NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
May 02 13:24:05 Kel-Omen systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
May 02 13:24:05 Kel-Omen systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Job NetworkManager.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
% journalctl -xeu NetworkManager.service
May 02 13:24:05 Kel-Omen systemd[1]: Starting NetworkManager.service - Network Manager...
 Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has begun execution
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

 A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has begun execution.

 The job identifier is 112974.
May 02 13:24:05 Kel-Omen NetworkManager[39088]: <info>  [1683059045.5841] NetworkManager (version 1.42.4) is starting... (after a restart, boot:389cae8a-8790-453c-a973-f4f8c13c9c4f)
May 02 13:24:05 Kel-Omen NetworkManager[39088]: <info>  [1683059045.5842] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
May 02 13:24:05 Kel-Omen NetworkManager[39088]: <error> [1683059045.5855] bus-manager: cannot connect to D-Bus: Error receiving data: Connection reset by peer
May 02 13:24:05 Kel-Omen NetworkManager[39088]: <info>  [1683059045.5855] exiting (error)
May 02 13:24:05 Kel-Omen systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Main process exited,             code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 Subject: Unit process exited
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

 An ExecStart= process belonging to unit NetworkManager.service has exited.

 The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
May 02 13:24:05 Kel-Omen systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Subject: Unit failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

 The unit NetworkManager.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
May 02 13:24:05 Kel-Omen systemd[1]: Failed to start NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
 Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

 A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished with a failure.

 The job identifier is 112974 and the job result is failed.
May 02 13:24:05 Kel-Omen systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 63.
 Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

 Automatic restarting of the unit NetworkManager.service has been scheduled, as the result for
 the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
May 02 13:24:05 Kel-Omen systemd[1]: Stopped NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
 Subject: A stop job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

 A stop job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished.

 The job identifier is 113304 and the job result is done.
May 02 13:24:05 Kel-Omen systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
 Subject: A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

 A start job for unit NetworkManager.service has finished with a failure.

 The job identifier is 113304 and the job result is dependency.
May 02 13:24:05 Kel-Omen systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Job NetworkManager.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

Comment: It looks like dbus isn’t started. Can you update question with output of `systemctl status dbus.service` and `journalctl -xeu dbus.service`?